# DevExpress WPF Grid - Event when columns width is changed

Tags: wpf, grid, devexpress

does anyone knows, which event is raised, when user changes width of column for WPF DevExpress grid? I want to use it to store columns widths in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do the same, but for the silverlight grid. The best i could get was to handle the Grid.LayoutUpdated event, and enumerate the columns to get their widths. I couldn't even bind to the column width property in the silverlight grid because it wasn't a dependency property, the WPF grid is most likely exactly the same.

EDIT:
what you could do though is check through the source code of the WPF grid, and add a ColumnResized event yourself. It's not ideal, because you would have to re-integrate the code everytime you installed a DevExpress update, and then rebuild the grid. You would also need to be careful how you do it, for instance you need to work out the best way to determine when a column resize has finished, so that you don't continually fire the event. Or you could look round for a more fully featured (more mature) grid?

Comment: I tried, this event is raised every 5 seconds automaticaly, that would  seriuosly slow down my app. So i think we must search for some better way or event.

Comment: Or maybe there we must thing some way to indicate, when the user updates the layout and when it raised automaticaly.

Comment: LostMouseCapture - works a little better, if noone would answer or suggest a better way,  I thing thats would the best way for my purpose.

Comment: I done hybridicaly, when LostMouseCapture raised,  iset property WithChanged to true, and in LayoutUpdated event i check if WithChanged is true. If it is, then i save my column withs.

Comment: Cool, glad you got a solution. I don't want to diss DevExpress too much and i've been using their stuff for a few years, but i seriously think they need to improve their game with their WPF and Silverlight controls - especially when even simple stuff like ColumnChanged events are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You Can store columns widths by event View.LostFocus:

DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl grc = new DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl();
grc.View.LostFocus += View_LostFocus;

And with handler:

```
 void View_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        TableView tv = sender as TableView;
        GridColumn[] gcs = tv.VisibleColumns.ToArray();
        foreach (GridColumn gc in gcs)
        {
            if (gc.ActualHeaderWidth != gc.Width)
            {
                double newWidth = gc.ActualHeaderWidth; //Do something with new width
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridColumnHeader exposes a SizeChanged event which passes the SizeChangedEventArgs object to you in which a lot of useful Sizes info is exposed!